# Symfony 3.4 crud delete

Tags: symfony3

Muy buenas chicos me he creado un proyecto  prueba con Symfony 3.4 Una vez creado la base de datos con su tabla y sus campos .En Symfony he ejecutado este comando php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud , he seguido todo el manual de aquí https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

Todo funciona bien  menos  el botón eliminar que no hace nada este es el error que me sale con phpstrom que yo creo que tendra algo que ver he buscado en google un  monton pero no encuentro nada que me pueda ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No te líes tanto y hazlo así:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="post_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
 */
public function delete(Request $request, Post $post): Response
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->remove($post);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('post_index');
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad, por favor trata de explicar los pasos que has echo